# python3でTreeTaggerを使う

Tags: python3

```
pip3 install treetaggerwrapper
```

上記のコマンドでTreeTaggerをインストールしたのですが

ttw.py

```
import treetaggerwrapper
import os

tagdir = os.getenv('TREETAGGER_ROOT')
tagger = treetaggerwrapper.TreeTagger(TAGLANG='en',TAGDIR=tagdir)
tags = tagger.TagText("This is a pen")
for tag in tags:
    print(tag)
```

TREETAGGER_ROOTが分からず確認する方法があれば教えてください

Answer (score 1):

以下に「TreeTagger のインストールディレクトリを指定しますが、bin に PATH が通っていれば空で問題ないようです。」とあります。
[TreeTagger を使ってソースコード中の単語をリストアップしてみた](http://srz-zumix.blogspot.jp/2016/10/treetagger.html)

[TreeTagger Python Wrapper’s documentation!](http://treetaggerwrapper.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)によると、自動的に検索されて、結果が $HOME/.config/treetagger_wrapper.cfg ファイルに書かれるようです。

環境変数が設定されていれば、コマンドプロンプトでそれを確認し、設定されていなければ、上記 .cfg ファイルを確認すれば良いでしょう。

Comment: ありがとうございます。PATHを通せば使用できました